# Elmah doesn't log exceptions using WebAPI with HttpResponseException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

In my WebApi code, I raise a HttpResponseException which short-circuits the request pipeline and generates a valid Http response. However, I'm trying to integrate webApi with elmah logging, yet the HttpResponseExeptions aren't showing up.

I have the web.config set-up for elmah and have the following code:

**In Global.asx.cs:**

```
static void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{  
    config.Filters.Add(new ServiceLayerExceptionFilter());            
    config.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
    config.DependencyResolver = new WebApiDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container);                            
}
```

**Filter:**

```
public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

**Code where exception is raised:**

```
public Task<FileUpModel> UploadFile()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {                
        var provider = new TolMobileFormDataStreamProvider("C:\images\");

        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {

            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

            var fileInfo = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault();
            if (fileInfo == null)
                // the exception here isn't logged by Elmah?!
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);    

            var uploadModel = new FileUpModel { success = true };
            return uploadModel;
        });

        return task;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
    }            
}
```

Can anyone who has implemented this before let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web API special cases HttpResponseException thrown in action and converts into HttpResponseMessage and hence you are not seeing your exception filter getting invoked.

This is not true in the case of throwing HttpResponseException from filters. However, ideally one need not throw HttpResponseException from filters as you could short-circuit a request by setting the Response property on the supplied input context.

Comment: You cannot. Your filter would get invoked only for non-HttpResponseExceptions when thrown from actions.

Comment: I used the manual Elmah error signalling when I create the HttpResponseException and this seems to work fine.

Comment: @jaffa What do you mean by that? Do you add try/catch blocks to your `ApiController` and then manually signal Elmah? While this will work to capture any `HttpResponseExeption` raised in your controller, you're still out of luck if one is raised anywhere else in the pipeline.

Comment: @KevinBabcock True. The ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter will catch all exceptions within the API controller as this provides is a single point of signalling. But my problem was inside code that was not part of the controller, hence the manual signal outside of the filter. I didn't find a way of catching this outside of the controller.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned above, the Elmah filter does not catch and log anything when you raise a HttpResponseException.  More specifically, if the following syntax is used:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "It was a bad request");
or
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "HttpResponseException - This request is not properly formatted"));
```

I wanted to trap and log an error in both cases.  The way to do it is to use an "ActionFilterAttribute", override "OnActionExecuted", and check actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    // when actionExecutedContext.Response is null, the error will be caught and logged by the Elmah filter
    if ((actionExecutedContext.Response != null) && !actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var messages = (System.Web.Http.HttpError)((System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<System.Web.Http.HttpError>)actionExecutedContext.Response.Content).Value;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var keyValuePair in messages) {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Message: Key - " + keyValuePair.Key + ", Value - " + keyValuePair.Value); 
            }
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Web API Failed Status Code returned - " + stringBuilder.ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Error in OnActionExecuted - " + ex.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, I also overwrote "OnActionExecuting" to validate the model state.  This allowed me to remove all of the checks within my actions.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.ModelState != null && !actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var obj in actionContext.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage)) {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Error: " + error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Invalid Model State -- " + stringBuilder.ToString()));
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to add the filter using "config.Filters.Add".

Comment: Yes, this is able to also catch HttpResponseException.

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn on Elmah for HttpFilters in order to get this to work as you expect for WebApi.

Use [Elmah.Contrib.WebApi](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi) available as a [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah.contrib.webpai), it will wire include a class that you can then wire up following the instructions on the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi project site.

If you want to do this yourself, [Capturing Unhandled Exceptions in ASP.NET Web API's with ELMAH](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx) walks you through what the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi is doing for you.

Additionally, I had to change the way that the error response is thrown for it to be picked by Elmah to:

```
 throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
```

I would also recommend the use of the [Elmah.MVC NuGet Package](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc).

Comment: Neither the project nor blog post you reference address the question raised by the @jaffa. Using an attribute or global filter to trap exceptions in an ASP.NET Web API project is well-documented around the web. What *isn't* well-documented is the fact that Web API calls ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnException() on your derived exception filter for every exception *except* when an `HttpResponseExeption` is thrown from an `ApiController`. In this case, Web API swallows the exception and your exception filter is never called. I've been searching for a workaround but have yet to find one.

Comment: This does not handle HttpResponseException